# Discord.js and mysql check for new database entry and output them?

Tags: mysql, discord.js

I connected my **mysql database** with my **nodejs** discord bot and I wanna check if a new entry is in my table and output them

I already have this:

```
connection.query('SELECT steamid FROM banned ORDER BY ID DESC LIMIT 1', (err,rows) => {
    if (err) throw err;

    data = JSON.stringify(rows);
    console.log(rows[0]);
})
```

kind regards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try something like this :

```
  /* Insert new thing into a database */
  let querySQL = 'SELECT steamid FROM banned ORDER BY ID DESC LIMIT 1';
  connection.query(querySQL)
    .then(results => {
      if (results.affectedRows > 0) {
        // Debug
        console.log(`SELECT results`, results);
        console.log(`1st result`, results[0]);

      }
    })
    .catch(e => {
      // Debug
      console.log(`[ERROR] SQL query`, e); 
    });
```

Read the [mysql documentation](https://www.npmjs.com/package/mysql) on npm for more help.